# shift right and shift left assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, zero-extension

If I want to say for example bx is a number:

```
shl bx,1
shr bx,1
```

What will be the new bx value? Does it stay the same?

Answer (score 3):

> What will be the new bx value? Does it stay the same?

No (or not necessarily). The `shl bx,1` will get rid of the highest bit, and the `shr bx,1` won't bring the old highest bit back. This means that a value like 0x8123 will become 0x0123.

Mostly, it'd be almost the same as using `and bx,0x7FFF` to clear the highest bit (except for the carry flag).

Comment: thank you for your help but i know that 
SHL BX,1;  BX=BX*2
SHR BX,1; BX=BX/2
so new value can be the same old value right?

Comment: @AmerSyouri: yes, if the original value had its high bit = 0, the final result will be the same as the input.  That's why the answer says "not necessarily" instead of always no.

Comment: For the one bit shift right after a shift left, the carry flag will be clear (matching what you get with `and`, but the overflow flag (OF) will be different (clear for `and`, the most significant bit of `bx` before the shift right - meaning it is set if the result changes from a negative to a positive one).